# PIC how to PPS mapping to normal input

Tags: pic

I am using PIC18F26K83 and I need to use interrupt on change on pin RC7. But interrupt does not work so I believe it is because of the PPS mapping. In default RC7 is for UART. I think when I set this pin to a normal input pin, problem will be solved. How can I do that? When I check the datasheet all I see are special function pins such as I2C, INTCON etc.

Comment: do you have any code that you are using to show what you are trying to achieve? Thanks

Comment: Well I am trying to map RC7 to normal input. Like RC7PPS=0; would this work?

Answer (score 1):

Setting RC7PPS to 0, would only set the output and not the input.

For PPS inputs, pins are not mapped to peripherals, instead peripheral inputs are mapped to pins (it's the other way around). At Power on reset (POR) , U1RXPPS is set to RC7 (0b10111) but is not active unless the U1 (Uart) peripheral is enabled.

In conclusion I don't think changing PPS mapping will solve your issue, it must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an digital IO you dont't need the `PPS` register.
You had to:

- keep care that the peripherals (e.g. I2C module, UART module...) are switched off
- keep care of the `TRIS` register (`1` for input / `0` for output)
- keep care that the pin is switched to digital with the `ANSEL` register (`0` for digital)